# Can't ping user because two users have the same username

Tags: bug, comment-replies

I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258993/react-useeffect-and-iterating-over-array-using-vimeo-api) and some one with the same name of the OP added a comment, now I have two @James

> [image]

I don't know wich one is the OP and I would like to tag the OP.

What do I do?

I also can't tag both

> [image]

Comment: If this is a comment on their post, don't do any @ at all; they'll get notified regardless.

Comment: If you look at the link of the question, you will see that it isn't a comment on their post... It's on my answer

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a bug, but a design limitation. SE has chosen to allow duplicate names, and that means that name-dependent functionality can't always discriminate between users.

Comment: My reading of the [MSE how to @replies work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) suggests that the James with the most recent activity will get the notification.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names

Comment: @Servy you found my dupe, thanks

Comment: "I also can't tag both" - correct; but that's because you can't tag more than one person, it is not a limitation caused by duplicate names.

Comment: @Gimby didn't know that, thanks for the info